# Is it possible to make smaller charts in bokeh? Or is it possible to lessen image size in python-pptx?

Tags: python, bokeh, python-pptx

I am going to embed bokeh plots into a powerpoint presentation. However, when I try to create a smaller chart by reducing plot height, the  plot is not entirely shown. 
Here is the code:

```
d={'name':['a','b','c','d'],
  'value':[800,1800,400,30]} 
df=pd.DataFrame(d)

src=ColumnDataSource(df)

pl=figure(plot_height=350,
          plot_width=500,
          x_range=src.data['name'].tolist())


labels = LabelSet(x='name', y='value', text='value',  level='glyph',
            x_offset=-13.5, y_offset=5, source=src, render_mode='canvas')

pl.vbar(x='name', top='value', width=.8, source=src)
pl.add_layout(labels)
export_png(pl, filename=OUTFILE+'slide_4.png')
```

And here is the result:
[Bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95ffA.png)

 
Is there a way to make smaller bokeh charts? If not, maybe there is a way to resize images in python-pptx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot is shown in its entirety. The clipping that you see is due to the fact that `LabelSet` is an annotation, and annotations are not taken into account when computing data ranges.

To fix the issue, either provide a larger padding to the default `DataRange1d` instance that is Y range, or just set the end of the range manually.